# dask - CountVectorizer returns "ValueError('Cannot infer dataframe metadata with a `dask.delayed` argument')"

Tags: dataframe, dask, countvectorizer

I have a Dask Dataframe with the following content:

```
    X_trn                                               y_trn
0   java repeat task every random seconds p m alre...   LQ_CLOSE
1   are java optionals immutable p d like to under...   HQ
2   text overlay image with darkened opacity react...   HQ
3   ternary operator in swift is so picky p questi...   HQ
4   hide show fab with scale animation p m using c...   HQ
```

I am trying to use CountVectorizer from dask.ml's library. When I do pass my X_trn to fit_transform, I get the Value Error "Cannot infer dataframe metadata with a `dask.delayed` argument'".

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
countMatrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(training['X_trn'])
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer will probably come too late for the original author but may still help others. The answer is actually in the [documentation](https://ml.dask.org/modules/generated/dask_ml.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) I also overlooked it at first:

> The Dask-ML implementation currently requires that raw_documents is a
> dask.bag.Bag of documents (lists of strings).

This apparently innocense sentence is your problem. You are passing a `dask.dataframe` and not a `dask.bag.Bag of documents`

```
import dask.bag as db
corpus = db.from_sequence(training['X_trn'], npartitions=2)
```

And then, you can pass it to the vectorizer as you were doing:

```
 X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
```